# sudo jps not locating MapReduce jobtracker

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, ports

I am running CDH5 on Ubuntu. I have installed everything i need, but when i type in sudo jps, the jobtracker is not displayed. Heres my configuration on mapred-site.xml

```
mapred.job.tracker.http.address: localhost{50030|50020}
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

what is your hadoop version? If it is 0.20.2+ then there is no need of configuring the jobtracker as they have removed the seperate jobtracker functionality. You can find it at localhost:8088.

Remove the configuration and restart the node

If it is an older version then try to manually start it using:

$hadoop jobtracker

if it doe not start, post the error log here

Comment: The JT now works. But now, the data node is suddenly dead, and cant wake up.

Comment: it keeps looping around 2014-09-01 01:21:49,457 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - DFS chooseDataNode: got # 2 IOException, will wait for 5902.097491458199 msec.


I have restarted the datanode over and over, but to no avail

Comment: sudo jps displays NN, SNN, JT and TT, but no DN

Comment: okay, 1.stop-all.sh
2.delete the hadoop-<username> at /tmp
 3.$hadoop namemode -format 4. start-all.sh

Comment: If it still does not work then you need to delete every thing in the folders namenode and datanode then format and restart